# SwiftUI: Cannot find type in scope

Tags: swiftui, observable

I'm having trouble coming up a good way to ask this question, so I'll instead show a simple example. I have a model, an `@ObservableObject`, that contains a struct:

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allData: [TheData] = []
    
    struct TheData: Hashable {
        let thePosition: Int
        let theChar: Character
    }
    
    func initState() {
        let allChars = Array("abd")
        for (index, element) in allChars.enumerated() {
            allData.append(TheData(thePosition: index, theChar: element))
        }
    }
}
```

In my view, I'm attempting to reach the model from two different structs (as a result of an annoying `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time..`), but I get an error:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var theModel = MyModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
            Text("Hello, world!")
            HStack {
                ForEach(theModel.allData, id: \.self) { theElement in
                    letterAcross(myLetter: theElement)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            theModel.initState()
        }
        .environmentObject(theModel)
    }
}

struct letterAcross: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var theModel: MyModel
    var myLetter: TheData // <----- the ERROR is here

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(String(myLetter.theChar))
        }
    }
}
```

The error is `Cannot find type TheData in scope`. It appears I am somehow messing up the `@StateObject` and `@EnvironmentObject`. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `var myLetter: MyModel.TheData` or put `TheData` out of (the scope of) `MyModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nested type, so it's `MyModel.TheData`:

```
var myLetter: MyModel.TheData
```